# Windows Media Center DVR TV Tuner and TV Guide Replacement

Tags: tv

Does Ubuntu have similar software to Windows Media Center, specifically the TV Tuner, TV Recording and TV Guide features.  WMC until recently was a great DVR tool.  The TV guide downloads to it, you can do a "season pass" to record TV programs, watch TV, pause, etc. Similar to "TIVO".  MS has made some changes and none of the resolutions seem to work and MS no longer includes WMC in it's base OS. If Ubuntu does not include similar software in the OS is there vendor software that will run on Ubuntu that will work in the same manner as WMC?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try either mythTV, or XBMC (Kodi)

MythTV is a free, open source media center and digital video recorder (DVR) distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL. With its plugin architecture, MythTV can be transformed into a home media center suite, capable of managing your personal photo, video, and music collections, as well as keep you up to date with the weather, a ZoneMinder home security system, and much, much more.<sup>[mythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/)</sup>

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mythtv
sudo mythtv-setup
```

Rebbot you system, and re-run the setup again

```
mythtv-setup
```

If you get a message saying that Myth could not connect to the database, check that the password on the screen matches the one in `/etc/mythtv/config.xml`

```
sudo cat /etc/mythtv/config.xml
```

XBMC(Kodi)XBMC started as “Xbox Media Center.” It’s designed to play back video from local files, network shares, or online streaming services. If you use your media center PC for playing back downloaded files or streaming Netflix, Hulu, YouTube, and other online sources, you’ll want XBMC.<sup>[Kodi](http://kodi.tv/download/)</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```